# 'Bundle' issues with ruby gem 'gamebox'

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems

I'm working with the gem 'gamebox' for the first time and I'm running into issues. I have the gem installed and generated the template the guide instructs me to, however when I attempt to bundle it it throws this error detailed below.

```
$ bundle install --path lib/dependencies
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.bundle install --path lib/dependencies
.......
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 0.9.2.2
Using hitimes 1.2.2
Using timers 4.0.1
Using celluloid 0.16.0
Using conject 0.1.8
Using cri 2.1.0
Using diff-lcs 1.2.5

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby2.1 extconf.rb 
checking for socket() in -lsocket... no
checking for gethostbyname() in -lnsl... yes
checking for atan() in -lm... yes
checking for inflate() in -lz... yes
checking for iconv_open() in -liconv... no
checking for libiconv_open() in -liconv... no
checking for libiconv_open() in -llibiconv... no
checking for iconv_open() in -llibiconv... no
checking for iconv_open() in -lc... yes
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -lxml2... no
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -llibxml2... no
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -lxml2... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby2.1
    --with-iconv-dir
    --without-iconv-dir
    --with-iconv-include
    --without-iconv-include=${iconv-dir}/include
    --with-iconv-lib
    --without-iconv-lib=${iconv-dir}/lib
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --with-socketlib
    --without-socketlib
    --with-nsllib
    --without-nsllib
    --with-mlib
    --without-mlib
    --with-zlib
    --without-zlib
    --with-iconvlib
    --without-iconvlib
    --with-iconvlib
    --without-iconvlib
    --with-libiconvlib
    --without-libiconvlib
    --with-libiconvlib
    --without-libiconvlib
    --with-clib
    --without-clib
    --with-xml2-config
    --without-xml2-config
    --with-xml2-dir
    --without-xml2-dir
    --with-xml2-include
    --without-xml2-include=${xml2-dir}/include
    --with-xml2-lib
    --without-xml2-lib=${xml2-dir}/lib
    --with-xml2lib
    --without-xml2lib
    --with-libxml2lib
    --without-libxml2lib
    --with-xml2lib
    --without-xml2lib
 extconf failure: need libxml2.

    Install the library or try one of the following options to extconf.rb:

      --with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config
      --with-xml2-dir=/path/to/libxml2
      --with-xml2-lib=/path/to/libxml2/lib
      --with-xml2-include=/path/to/libxml2/include


extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/user_id/company_office/lib/dependencies/ruby/2.1.0/gems/libxml-ruby-2.8.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/user_id/company_office/lib/dependencies/ruby/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/libxml-ruby-2.8.0/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing libxml-ruby (2.8.0), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install libxml-ruby -v '2.8.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I've attempted to use `gem install libxml-ruby -v '2.8.0'` as well as `sudo gem install libxml-ruby -v '2.8.0'` which outputs the following:

```
$ gem install libxml-ruby -v '2.8.0'
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/libxml-ruby-2.8.0/HISTORY
```

I'm newish to ruby and linux so apologies if this is a silly question.
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you're missing required C libraries. At a guess I'd say you need to install libxml2-dev (or whatever it's called in your flavour of Linux's package manager).

Comment: Glad I could help - could you accept the answer please (click the tick to the left of the question).

Comment: Gamebox has tests that it runs on TravisCI servers. The setup has a list of install requirements for linux: https://github.com/shawn42/gamebox/blob/master/.travis.yml#L10-L12